# How to switch to front camera when i double tap ( SWIFT )

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, tap

at first i want to apologize for my approximative english.

I work on a Project for Iphone using swift.

In my project, I have 3 views in one of them i put  a camera view (the back camera) just like the  Snapchat menu. when I double tap I want it to switch with to the front camera.

I added a Tap gesture Recognizer to my code  but i don't know how to initialize my Front Camera in it.

Here's the complete code.
If you need more info tell me! Thank you.

```
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation


    class View2: UIViewController,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?


@IBAction func DoubleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {


}


@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.






}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080





//  Déclaration Caméra frontale








    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    var error : NSError?
    var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        input = nil
    }

    if (error == nil && captureSession?.canAddInput(input) != nil){

        captureSession?.addInput(input)

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) != nil){
            captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            captureSession?.startRunning()


        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Oooups nothing , i edited it. I want to add a function who switch the camera view to the front camera when I double tap my screen using this method. @LyndseyScott

Comment: check answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40353301/5147817)

Answer (score 0):

may be this help

```
- (AVCaptureDevice *)showFrontCamera {
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            return device;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This is the function which will return the front camera view. When you double click call this function to switch

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [self showFrontCamera];
```

I have code in Objective-c, may be you can convert it into swift as per your need.

Comment: Thank you , but i tried to convert this into swift but it doesn't work :( @Krupanshu